# Type or namespace UI does not exist in the namespace system.web

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am unable to use the JavascriptSerializer as provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8
I am getting the error  `error CS0234: The  type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` The using statement is causing this error.
I am using visual studio code

**Steps Taken:**
I included system.web.dll inside the bin folder and provide a path to it in the .csproj
file. But the error is still the same.

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core/ .NET 5+? Because, unless you're using .NET Framework, then the `JavaScriptSerializer` is gone and you should use [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) and its [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I actually just started into C# . I am running the command `dotnet run` to run my program in the terminal. The .csproj contains `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` as the top line. I am using visual studio code as an editor. I am not sure which of the three you mentioned is being used.  Is there a way to verify it?

Comment: @MindSwipe is JavaScriptSerializer an old library?

Comment: If you're using the CLI to do things, then you're using .NET Core or .NET 5+ (.NET 5 is just .NET Core 4 but renamed). .NET Core is the new cross platform re-write of .NET, and as such there are things they dropped from it, the `JavaScriptSerializer` being one of those things. In short, yes, `JavaScriptSerializer` is old and shouldn't be used anymore unless you're using a version of the .NET Framework *older* than 4.7.2